# Is it safe to use MySQL triggers in PHP software that will be installed on many random hostings

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, web-hosting

How common are MySQL triggers these days - does the vast majority of hostings have the adequate MySQL server installed?

Comment: This question is likely to be closed for being too broad. Can you give us a more specific use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you ask for a dedicated hosting or similar such as VPS hosting, i wouldnt try using too much anything else outside of tables.

Most shared/reseller configurations will have issues with permissions regarding VIEWs, TRIGGERS and STORED PROCEDURES.

If you don't mind requiring dedicated hosting for your app, then i think you're safe to use these.

Comment: I believe that this is true, because many shared hosts use a single instance of MySQL shared between many users.  To be more clear. The MySQL server might support triggers, but the user accessing the database most likely does not have access to use triggers.

Comment: Indeed, if i remember right, this is because usage of VIEWS, TRIGGERS and STORED PROC is granted at the server level (for the creation) so most shared hosters cannot grant this permission...

Comment: See documentation here, "Before MySQL 5.1.6, the SUPER privilege was required to create or drop triggers." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Then you have to see my popular web hosters, they are definitely doing something wrong... :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the vast majority, but I wouldn't choose a provider where I wasn't allowed to do triggers and stored procedures.

Triggers are amazingly powerful and very hard to live without when doing advanced stuff, especially things like upgrades without downtime and migrating data between tables.

I would say that triggers are very common on serious set ups but almost never present in early stages of a database.

Just my 50 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would be fine.  According to the MySQL documentation, triggers have been supported since MySQL 5.0.2:

> Support for triggers is included beginning with MySQL 5.0.2.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

That version has been around for awhile, starting with the release of 5.0 in October 2005:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Product_history

So, I'm guessing this will work for you and unless it's installed on a REALLY OLD host it should work.